# Can we create different class instance using Java generics by passing class type as argument

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I am trying to create object from a xml file. Currently I am providing the Class type to be parsed in the method signature. For instance TestRequest as you see in the below code. Due to this I cannot use the same method to create another object type. Is it possible to write a method, probably using generics, to return different class instance by passing class type as parameter.

**Current Code:**

```
  private static JAXBElement<TestRequest> createRequestObject(String xmlFile) {

    JAXBElement<VerifyRequest> result;
    try {
      JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestRequest.class);
      Unmarshaller unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
      String xmlString = loadFile(xmlFile);
      result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes())), VerifyRequest.class);
    } catch (JAXBException | IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Expecting something like

```
private static <T> JAXBElement<T> createRequestObject(String xmlFile, Class objectType) {
```

Comment: What problem do you have with passing the class as parameter?

Comment: with the above signature how can java infer that T is of Class objectType?

Comment: Just pass `Class<T>` as parameter.

Comment: `String xmlString = loadFile(xmlFile);` — Don’t hold the entire file in memory.  Use `new StreamSource(new File(xmlFile))` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
private static <T> JAXBElement<T> 
createRequestObject (String xmlFile, Class<T> type)
```

That should be enough.

If you call `createRequestObject(file, TestRequest.class)`, `T` is resolved to be `TestRequest` and thus the return type would be `JAXBElement<TestRequest>`. Similar for other types.

Comment: Thanks for your help